# Team commits grouped by a member

Tags: gerrit

I use the following URL to see a team member's commits:

```
https://server.com/gerrit/#/q/owner:member1+status:open
```

I want to see commits from all members, so I wrote this URL:

```
https://server.com/gerrit/#/q/(owner:member1 OR ... owner:memberN)+ status:open
```

Now I have the commits from all team members, but they are not grouped by a member. Could you please tell me the correct URL?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do that.

Comment: Thank you! Can I do that in "My"->"Changes"->"Incoming reviews" table?